# Create n data sets from one data set without repetition using stratified sampling

Tags: r, random

I have a data set `train` which has say 500 rows, I would like to get a data frame with n columns each containing `500/n` values(row numbers without repetition in other columns) basing on stratified sampling of a column in train, say `train$y`.

I have tried the following but it returns duplicate values,

```
library(caret)
n <- 10 # I want to divide my data set in to 10 parts
data_partition <- createDataPartition(y = train$y, times = 10, 
                                 p = 1/n, list = F)
```

To summarize with an example, 
If I have a data set `train` with 100 rows and one of the column `train$y`(value= 0 or 1). I would like to get 10 data sets with 10 rows each from the train and they should be [stratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) basing on `train$y` and they should not be seen on other 9 data sets.

Example input:

```
ID  x   y
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   1
4   1   1
5   2   1
6   4   1
7   4   0
8   4   1
9   3   1
10  1   1
11  2   1
12  3   0
13  4   1
14  5   1
15  6   1
16  10  1
17  9   1
18  3   0
19  7   0
20  8   1
```

Expected output (4 first column, with details of each set aside)

```
ID  x   y   sample      set 1           set 2           set 3   
1   1   0   set 2       ID  x   y       ID  x   y       ID  x   y
2   2   0   set 3       8   4   1       11  2   1       17  9   1
3   3   1   set 3       9   3   1       12  3   0       5   2   1
4   1   1   set 3       10  1   1       13  4   1       6   4   1
5   2   1   set 3       18  3   0       1   1   0       7   4   0
6   4   1   set 3       19  7   0       14  5   1       2   2   0
7   4   0   set 3       20  8   1       15  6   1       3   3   1
8   4   1   set 1                       16  10  1       4   1   1
9   3   1   set 1                                               
10  1   1   set 1                                               
11  2   1   set 2                                               
12  3   0   set 2                                               
13  4   1   set 2                                               
14  5   1   set 2                                               
15  6   1   set 2                                               
16  10  1   set 2                                               
17  9   1   set 3                                               
18  3   0   set 1                                               
19  7   0   set 1                                               
20  8   1   set 1
```

In the above example given input as `ID,x` and `y`. **I would like to get the column `sample`** which I can segregate into those 3 tables(to the right) whenever I want to.

**Please observe, the `y` in the data has `14- 1s` and `6- 0s` which are in the ratio of `70:30` and the output sets are almost in similar ratio.**

Sample dataset in a copy/run friendly format:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:20, x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 8L), y = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: please generate an example dataset together with your expected output

Comment: See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/sampling.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @zx8754, I found the solution for this in the caret package.--------
library(caret);
k <- createFolds(data$y,k = 3,list = F);
addmargins(table(k,data$y))

Comment: Great, consider posting your working solution as answer for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks @zx8754, just did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the `caret` package. Try the code below

```
# Createing dataset
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:20, x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 8L), y = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
# Solution
library(caret)
k <- createFolds(data$y,k = 3,list = F)
addmargins(table(k,data$y))
```